# On motherboard with SATA3, which circumstances would make the disk-light to stay on continuously?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, sata, diagnostic

On a motherboard with a SATA3 controller, which circumstances[1] would make the disk-light stay on without a flicker?

---

[1] At that stage - the computer is completely unresponsive, and only a reboot will revive it.
Syslog is different every time this happens (about twice a month), so no clue what the root-cause may be.

Comment: Many different circumstances.

Comment: The light would flicker while the disk was being accessed.

Comment: Try to look in the Event Viewer. Run chkdsk. Examine the SMART data of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive activity light functionality is normally provided by the motherboard itself at a very low level, probably directly from any onboard SATA controller or the chipset.  It's not an OS controlled thing at all.

So my best guesses are things like:

- power issues
- temperature issues
- issues with physical connection, such as power connections or PCIe cards not inserted fully or correctly.
- motherboard defect issues

I would:

- Update to latest firmware to ensure CPU has latest microcode.
- Chipset may be overheating.  Make sure a GPU isn't right next to it or something similar and making it too hot.
- If you have any PCIe cards, they may be defective.
- Replace power supply.

If it persists after that, it's probably a CPU or motherboard issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @LawrenceC. However, seems to me that the issues you suggested would probably occur _repeatedly_, not _about twice a month_, as they happen now.

Comment: Power issues are weird.  Maybe you have something high voltage on your same power circuit that is powered up twice a month that makes the power less stable.  Any high reliability system needs a power-conditioning UPS attached to it.